# C++ codes that seem similar but have differents behavior : any idea why?

Tags: c++, return-value

I have a c++ code of a segment tree that often it works, but with
a big input it fails. Any way, tracking the bug I have figured out that
changing some part of the code for something that seems to be "equivalent"
the code works without failures.

Some context :

```
struct state {
    int v, pos;
    state (int v, int pos) : v(v), pos(pos)  {}
};
int split(state s);
state go(state, int, int, int);

struct node{
    int link;
...
};
vector<node> t;
```

This code doesn't work :

```
int get_link (int v) {
    if (t[v].link != -1)  return t[v].link;
    if (t[v].par == -1)  return 0;

    int to = get_link (t[v].par);
    state aux = go (state (to,t[to].len()), t[v].l + (t[v].par==0), t[v].r, t[v].i_str);

    return t[v].link = split (aux);
}
```

This one works :

```
int get_link (int v) {
    if (t[v].link != -1)  return t[v].link;
    if (t[v].par == -1)  return 0;

    int to = get_link (t[v].par);
    state aux = go (state (to,t[to].len()), t[v].l + (t[v].par==0), t[v].r, t[v].i_str);

    int ret = split (aux);
    t[v].link = ret;
    return ret;
}
```

This one works :

```
int get_link (int v) {
    if (t[v].link != -1)  return t[v].link;
    if (t[v].par == -1)  return 0;

    int to = get_link (t[v].par);
    state aux = go (state (to,t[to].len()), t[v].l + (t[v].par==0), t[v].r, t[v].i_str);

    int ret = split (aux);
    t[v].link = ret;
    return t[v].link;
}
```

This one doesn't works :

```
int get_link (int v) {

    node &w = t[v];
    if (w.link != -1)  return w.link;
    if (w.par == -1)  return 0;

    int to = get_link (w.par);
    state aux = go (state (to,t[to].len()), w.l + (w.par==0), w.r, w.i_str);

    int ret = split (aux);
    w.link = ret;
//  assert(t[v].link == ret);

    return ret;
}
```

moreover, in this last case the assert fails.
it is weird because in all the failures cases, the get_line function runs many times
without problems.

Any idea what is wrong or what I am misunderstanding.

if it is useful

> $ gcc -v Using built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=gcc
>   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/lto-wrapper
>   Target: x86_64-redhat-linux Configured with: ../configure
>   --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --disable-build-with-cxx --disable-build-poststage1-with-cxx --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux Thread model: posix gcc version 4.7.2 20120921 (Red Hat 4.7.2-2) (GCC)

Comment: Almost certainly undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems pretty likely that your split function is resizing the `t` vector. So in an expression like this `t[v].link = split (aux)` if the `vector::operator[]` is being evaluated before the split call (which is possible) and the split function is reallocating the vector then you may be accessing a reference to an object which no longer exists.

Your alternative code, which uses a temporary variable, doesn't have this problem because then the call to `vector::operator[]` definitely happens after the call to split.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what is happening. The function split resizes the vector.
Thanks a lot. Your answer was very useful.

do you think that using a auxiliary variable is the best option? or more elegant ?
is there any way of avoiding this kind of problems ?

Comment: There are a few possibilities. You could use a container that doesn't *invalidate iterators* on a resize like `std::list`. You could preallocate the vectors storage using `vector::reserve`, but I think a temporary variable is fine. Maybe add a code comment indicating why it is necessary.

Comment: Of course `std::list` doesn't have an `operator[]`, `std::map<int,node>` would be a better choice.

Comment: I am implementing a tree with an array. The tree can bee to large and it grows dynamically, so std:list and vector::reserve  don't seem good options. I go for comment the code.
thanks!.

Comment: I was reading the assembly code of the function get_link.
is it a bug in the compiler the fact that it evaluates t[v] before the function split?
do you know if there are any reason to do it in this way?

Comment: No it's not a bug, if you have A = B; then there is nothing in C++ that says B has to be evaluated before A. It's just that normally A is something simple like a variable so we get used to the idea that there is no order of evaluation issue. The reason your compiler does it that way is harder to know. Another compiler could do it the other way round. Basically C++ leaves things like this up to the compiler writers to allow them to generate more efficient code.